# SQL injection in OdbcCommand.Parameters on PostgreSQL?

Tags: .net, postgresql, odbc, sql-injection

Assume that you have this code in C#/.NET (using PostgreSQL via ODBC):

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
...
OdbcCommand cmd = ...;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email=?;";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add("email", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = aEmail;
```

But when aEmail == \' (backslash and apos.) then it gives me following error:

```
Exception type: OdbcException 
Exception message: ERROR [42601] ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'\''';";
Error while executing the query
```

As I've read, using OdbcCommand.Parameters should protect against SQL injection, but in this case it looks like something doesn't works right, what am I missing?

Important note: I've never used PostgreSQL, ODBC, .NET before (started today, but I hope to end it today too ;), but I need to fix 4 SQL queries in one simple web application - previously there was:

```
System.Format("SELECT ... email = {0}", aEmail)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to escape the single quote? the problem is that to escape the single quote in PostgreSQL you should escape it with another single quote and not with backslash :

```
''''
```

However the ODBC driver should do this for you automatically passing only the single quote... Try to update with the latest version of the ODBC driver, if the problem persist maybe it is better to open an issue to the postgreSQL [bug mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/) .

Comment: I'm using that \' to do simple sql-injection test. I'm not escaping anything, because I believe that OdbcCommand.Parameters do it for me (which should work for any DB). It looks like parameter \' has been escaped as \'', but problem is that first backslash. Also if possible I would like to not update anything (don't want to break working app.). I'll try to post in PostgreSQL if on SO I won't get a solution.

Comment: Try updating with the latest version, i think could be a bug of the ODBC driver ...

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4.1, ODBC driver is PostgreSQL ANSI ODBC 8.02.01.00 (2006-08-31) - way too old, so it might be it. Thanks I'll try to update.

Comment: You was right, problem with old&buggy ODBC driver. Updating to latest version fixed problem. Thank you.